# Implement a token based authentication mechanism for iot devices on AWS IoT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, token, iot, aws-iot

I'm currently working on a project where I need to smoothen the process of device onboarding to the AWS IoT Core service.

Currently the onboarding process is:

```
I create the Thing in the AWS Console

I create the certs

I save the certs to laptop

I copy cert contents into the devices into the respective fields.
```

This feels incredibly manual :(

Are there any ways in which the process can be eased out, by using just token based authentication where, when the thing is being created on AWS IoT Core (from a web-app by using nodejs sdk), a token is generated and that token needs to be passed along by the device in the "client id" field from the device when connecting to the AWS IoT Core.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want to have a proper security mechanism in place, I'd suggest to use Fleet provisioning. You can have a bootstrap cert on your device that would allow to communicate with Fleet provisioning service in AWS IoT Core and obtain less constrained certificate. Using token is also supported in AWS IoT Core (using Custom authorizer), but this is mostly for legacy systems that do not support certificate authentication.